# When are my fluid approximations wrong?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, error-analysis, approximations, navier-stokes

I did some classical approximations of the Navier Stokes equations, fluid is:

- non-viscous
- incompressible
- irrotational

When are these approximations wrong? and particularly is there a "general method" to evaluate in a theoretical way "the error" of an approximation?
For example, for a given fluid with a given velocity flow, what will be the order of the terms that I neglect?

I see some methods using dimensionnal analysis, but it wasn't very clear for me...

Comment: To "evaluate the cost", a procedure may be: start with the initial condition and let it evolve in two ways: first, under the full problem (compressible Navier-stokes), and second under the approximate scheme. Consider now some "functional distance" between the two solutions and see how it grows in time (e.g. the "distance" defined via some "norm" of this kind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space, typically $L_2$). Sounds like a difficult analysis problem, not sure if there are general results, but partial ones probably yes.

Comment: @Quillo if I correctly understand your comment your propose a numerical estimation, but I'm looking for a more theorical way. Thanks for your comment, I'll make my question clearer about this.

Comment: @lufydad I am thinking about a mathematical one: when I say "solve the equations" you can do that on the computer and estimate numerically the "difference" or you can assume that the two solutions are the solutions of the corresponding problem and do mathematical estimates. I think mathematical physicists are interested in this kind of problem that is similar to the one of "Lyapunov exponents" in chaos theory (how much two "close" solutions differ after a certain amount of time?): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent

Comment: @Quillo what do you mean by "do mathematical estimates" ? I don't understand how to use Lyapunov exponents in this case...

Comment: I mean that the problem is philosophically similar to one of the Lyapunov exponents, so the same kind of mathematics may be used ("mathematical estimates": high-level use of the theory of partial differential equations and normed spaces, namely all the tricks and heavy analysis machinery typically used by mathematical physicists to study dynamical systems). The general problem is probably out of reach but there should be partial analytical results in the literature. For a full analysis, numerical simulation is the only way to go (simulate the full problem VS approximated one).

Comment: Ok it's more clear thank you ! I think I am looking for a less precise estimation, something like : the term I neglect is quadratic with the velocity flow evolution. Do you see what I mean ? Do you think this is out of scope too, for a "simple" analysis ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fluid dynamics has developed a systematic method to easily identify the correct approximations pertaining to different regimes. It is based on a set of dimensionless numbers expressing the *typical* ratio between different terms in Navier-Stokes, and related equations for the dynamics of fluids. The basic idea is that using typical lengths, velocities, times, etc., as units for the physical quantities appearing in the equations, it is possible to understand which terms can be neglected as a first approximation and possibly be re-introduced in a perturbative way, if necessary.

I suggest you refer to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_numbers_in_fluid_mechanics) for starting information and quite an extensive list of possible dimensionless numbers.

Here I'll briefly illustrate the technique with an example.
Let's assume that we want to understand when finite compressibility plays a role in fluid dynamics. We can start with an equation containing density ($\rho$) variation and the velocity field (${\bf u}$), the continuity equation:
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot \left( {\rho \bf u} \right)=0.
$$

By introducing the *material derivative* ($\frac{D}{Dt}$) and the equation of state to use pressure as a variable, it may be rewritten as
$$
\frac{1}{\rho c^2}\frac{Dp}{Dt}+\nabla \cdot {\bf u}=0, \tag{1}
$$
where $c$ is the speed of sound. At this point, we can introduce a typical length ($L$), a typical speed of the fluid ($U$), and a typical density ($\bar\rho$), and we can use them as new units. Equation ($1$) becomes:
$$
\frac{U^2}{\rho^* c^2}\frac{Dp^*}{Dt^*}+\nabla \cdot {\bf u}^*=0, \tag{2}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
t^* &= \frac{Ut}{L}\\
{\bf u}^*&=\frac{{\bf u}}{U}\\
p^*&=\frac{p}{\bar\rho U^2}\\
\rho^*&=\frac{\rho}{\bar \rho}
\end{align}
$$
and, by introducing the dimensionless Mach number $M=\frac{U}{c}$, we get
$$
\frac{M^2}{\rho^*}\frac{Dp^*}{Dt^*}+\nabla \cdot {\bf u}^*=0, \tag{2}
$$
Therefore, the importance of finite compressibility is encoded in the value of the dimensionless Mach's number. When it is negligible, the flow behaves as incompressible ($\nabla \cdot {\bf u}^* = 0$). If it is large, spatio-temporal variations of density cannot be neglected. Moreover, one could systematically introduce their effect perturbatively. However, we have to take into account that one requires some care from the mathematical point of view since the limit $M \rightarrow 0$ is non-trivial, changing the character of the resulting differential equations (see, for instance, the topic [singular perturbation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_perturbation) on Wikipedia).

Comment: Could you give a bit more details on how you go from equation (2) to conclusion of the parameter $M$ ?

Comment: @GiorgioP brilliant answer.

Comment: In typical aeronautical calculations, we assume flow is incompressible when M<0.3 (or so). The implication is that around M=0.3, we get an error in density of about 10%, which is usually acceptable.

Comment: What do you mean by "dimensional Mach number"? It is dimensionless...

Comment: In the derivation of equation (1), do you just assume that the partial derivative of density with respect to pressure is taken at constant entropy? Or is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Procyon Dimensional was a typo. Corrected. Thanks. About the derivative, yes, it is at constant entropy.. The underlying assumption is that the time scale for internal energy relaxation of a fluid element is much longer than typical dynamical times.

Answer (score 7):

> When are these approximations wrong ?

Almost all real fluids will have some viscosity (an exception may be superfluid helium-4) and some degree of compressibility. And there are simple situations where flow is not necessarily irrotational e.g. flow between two concentric cylinders. So one or more of the assumptions of your model are almost always going to be incorrect. The model may still give useful results in some circumstances.

I am not sure of the meaning of the second part of your question, about the "cost" of an approximation.

Comment: Sorry I realize that the term "cost" is quite confusing.
By "cost" I mean the order of the terms that I neglect, is it more clear ?

Comment: @lufydad I think instead of "cost" you mean "error."

Answer (score 0):

I want to focus on the part of the question that deals with viscous effects: The dimensionless version of the conservation of linear momentum is largely equal to its dimensional version, except the term that deals with the stress tensor: In the dimensionless version, the divergence of the stress tensor is divided by the Reynolds number. Thus, for high Reynolds number flows, the shear stresses in the fluid get negligible. (The surface stresses on the boundary do not.) See, for example, Schlichting, Gersten (2017): Boundary-Layer Theory, Section 4.1 "Similarity Laws", equation 4.4.